# How to match regex if a character is only present a specific number of times at a specific place

Tags: regex, regular-language

I am trying to write a regex to catch if the input is like that

```
>>item<<price!quantity
```

, but I have trouble with the "<<" part, because my regex also catches if it looks like that

```
>>item<<<price!quantity
```

, but that is not correct, because the "<<" part is "<<<" and it has to be only "<<", not "<" or "<<<"

The regex that came as close as possible

```
^>>\w.*<{2}\d.*!\d.*
```

Comment: so with the example `>>item<<price!quantity` what are you trying to return? or are you just trying to make sure it matches the whole line? ... Also, will the words "item", "price", and "quantity" be anything else?

Comment: @Nefariis I get input that can be either >>item<<price!quantity or >>item<<<price!quantity and if it is >>item<<price!quantity then it must return "true" else "false"

Comment: does it actually use item, price, quantity? or are those place holders?

Comment: @Nefariis
This is the real input 
>>Sofa<<312.23!3
, so they are placeholders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to your pattern you can fix it by adding a `(?<!<)` negative lookbehind before the `<<`:

```py
^>>\w.*(?<!<)<<\d.*!\d.*
#      ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o7baZo/1). Note `<<` is shorter than `<{2}` and `(?<!<)` makes sure there is no other `<` before the `<<` substring.